# How to change from string to list when converting from CSV to JSON?

Tags: python, json, string, list, csv

I found this code in order to convert a CSV file into JSON. What I need is to covert the Policy ID field to a list. Therefore, the PolicyID shouldn't be enclosed into the quote marks "" and should have a square bracket []. Here is the code I used:

```
import csv
import json


# Function to convert a CSV to JSON
# Takes the file paths as arguments
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    # create a dictionary
    data = {}

    # Open a csv reader called DictReader
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        # Convert each row into a dictionary
        # and add it to data
        for rows in csvReader:
            # Assuming a column named 'No' to
            # be the primary key
            key = rows['Username']
            data[key] = rows
            

    # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()
    # function to dump data
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


# Driver Code

# Decide the two file paths according to your
# computer system
csvFilePath = r'template.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'template.json'

# Call the make_json function
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

---

Here is what my csv file looks like:

[image]

Username   First Name   Last Name  Email Address      PolicyID  Group
jazmin00!  Jazmin       Parker     jazmin@gmail.com   555       A
jon00!     Jon          Dimer      jon@gmail.com      222       B

Here is the JSON file output:

```
{
    "jazmin00!": {
        "Username": "jazmin00!",
        "First Name": "Jazmin",
        "Last Name": "Parker",
        "Email Address": "jazmin@gmail.com",
        "PolicyID": "555",
        "Group": "A"
    },
    "jon00!": {
        "Username": "jon00!",
        "First Name": "Jon",
        "Last Name": "Dimer",
        "Email Address": "jon@gmail.com",
        "PolicyID": "222",
        "Group": "B"
    }
}
```

Here is What I am trying to accomplish:

```
{
    "jazmin00!": {
        "Username": "jazmin00!",
        "First Name": "Jazmin",
        "Last Name": "Parker",
        "Email Address": "jazmin@gmail.com",
        "PolicyID": [555],
        "Group": "A"
    },
    "jon00!": {
        "Username": "jon00!",
        "First Name": "Jon",
        "Last Name": "Dimer",
        "Email Address": "jon@gmail.com",
        "PolicyID": [222],
        "Group": "B"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions what I can do here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a for loop that works for what you are trying to accomplish:

```
for item in data:
    policy_id = []
    policy_id.append(int(data[item]['PolicyID']))
    data[item]['PolicyID'] = policy_id
```